# CSS background color transition issue

Tags: css

I have been having some issues with the code below. Tried looking up for mistakes. Basically, wish to change background-colour of the submit-button.

```
.submit-button{
    letter-spacing: 0.15em;
    height: 125px;
    width: 300px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 200%;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgb(219, 18, 18);
    color: white;
    border-color: transparent;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
    transition-duration: 0.7s;
    transition-property: background-color;
}

.submit-button:hover{
    background-color: indigo;
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is the HTML code:

```
<!--This is my button-->
<p class= "three">
<div class= "submit-button">
    Submit
</p>
```

Comment: can you post the related html code too? And it will be good to make it as snippet.

Comment: It works perfectly with this CSS with html code `<button class="submit-button">Submit</button>`. Can you create [a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I think the issue in HTML Code.

Answer (score 0):

The above code looks fine, I'd check the class name

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, browsers sometimes have trouble parsing `transition-property` values that contains dashes. A workaround would be to replace `transition-property: background-color` with `transition-property: all`. See if that fixes your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code and it is working fine. But I would like to share some suggestions.

- You should use a **button** element instead of **div**.
- In case, you still want to use div then kindly give proper height and width so it looks like a button.
- In your code, you have not closed the div tag.

I hope the above suggestion will help you.